# Reverse deduction theorem for predicate logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I cannot find a name for this metatheorem. By reverse deduction theorem I mean $\Gamma \vdash \phi \to \psi$ implies $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \psi$. There is another question regarding this but for propositional logic.

I am asked to prove $\Gamma \vdash \phi \to \psi$ implies $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \psi$ when $\Gamma, \phi, \psi$ are all sentences. I have to prove this given the following rules:

[image]

Now, my proof is as follows:

We can derive $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$ by the *thinning rule*. We also have $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \phi$ by assumption. Then by modus ponens  $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \psi$.

But, to me it seems that this proof should work when dropping the restriction of sentences. So why did the exercise require that they be sentences? Am I missing something?

Comment: I definitely agree with your proof, and it checks out with the rules you've shown from your textbook. As far as the wording of the question, I would like to point out that the question only asks that you show that it is true when $\Gamma, \phi,$ and $\psi$ are sentences, and doesn't necessarily require that it's false otherwise. I think it may just be an unnecessary detail

Comment: Deduction Th corresponds to [Conditional proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) aka: Conditional Introduction. The "reverse" corresponds to [Conditional Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) i.e. Modus Ponens.